# A better way than using multiple elseif statements?

Tags: php

Is there a cleaner way to achieve a similar result, but without using all of these elseif statements? I need there to always be a true statement, depending on dynamic variables. Thanks!

```
  $a = true;
  $b = false;
  $c = false;

  if ($a == true && $b == false && $c == false) {
    echo 'only $a is running';
  } elseif ($a == true && $b == false && $c == true) {
      echo '$a and $c are running, but not $b';  
  } elseif ($a == true && $b == true && $c == false) {
      echo '$a and $b are running, but not $c';
  } elseif ($a == false && $b == true && $c == true) {
      echo '$b and $c are running, but not $a';
  } elseif ($a == false && $b == false && $c == true) {
      echo 'only $c is running';
  } elseif ($a == false && $b == true && $c == false) {
      echo 'only $b is running';
  } else {
      echo 'nope';
  };
```

Comment: Put the values into an array; iterate over it and sort them into two arrays, running and not running; format one of three possible strings, "Only ...", "... are but not ..." and "nope".

Comment: Try [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

Comment: looks nicer, does the same thing

Comment: Is your question also to produce exactly those outputs, or are those just for testing, and would your code in those `if` blocks differ? It looks strange to include the name of a variable in the output... Users should not have anything have to do with those names.

Comment: Snarky answer: `$a = true; $b = false; $c = false; echo 'only $a is running';` as you've hard-coded `$a`, `$b`, and `$c`. :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider to use an array, that way you can make more alphabet letters than you have in your example right now, and it will just work:

```
<?php
$arr = [
  'a' => true,
  'b' => true,
  'c' => true
  ];

$running = [];
$not_running = [];
foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
  if ($val)
    $running[] = $key;
  else
    $not_running[] = $key;

if (count($running) == 0)
  echo "Nope";
else if (count($running) == 1)
  echo "Only ".$running[0]." is running";
else if (count($not_running) == 0)
  echo "All are running";
else
  echo "Only " . implode($running, ' and ') . " are running, but not ". implode($not_running, ' and ');
```

So now you can make your array bigger, for example like this:

```
for($i=0; $i<=25; $i++)
{
  $arr[chr($i+97)] = (bool)rand(0,1);
}
```

which will output something like:

```
Only c and d and e and f and g and h and l and m and n and q and u and w and y and z are running, but not a and b and i and j and k and o and p and r and s and t and v and x
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one potential way you could do it by utilising `__toString()`, it's pretty rushed so you'll probably want to clean it up a bit. You can find a working example [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/69d8d0037858fb331762d1ba2b6d7cb4d2c185df)

You may want to play with the `__toString()` return to get it to what you want, but essentially you just have to echo the collection.

Side note: I didn't implement `Countable`, `ArrayAccess`, `Iterator` or any other useful inbuilt interfaces due to time constraints. If you were to use this solution i'd suggest implementing them

```
<?php

class Instance
{
    /** @var string */
    private $name;

    /** @var bool */
    private $active;

    public function __construct($name, $active = false)
    {
        $this->name   = $name;
        $this->active = $active;
    }

    public function turnOn()
    {
        $this->active = true;
    }

    public function turnOff()
    {
        $this->active = false;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getActive()
    {
        return $this->active;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        $state = $this->getActive() === true ? 'on' : 'off';
        return sprintf("%s is switched %s", $this->getName(), $state);
    }
}

class InstanceCollection
{
    private $collection = [];

    public function add(Instance $item)
    {
        $this->collection[] = $item;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        $on  = $this->getInstancesByState(true);
        $off = $this->getInstancesByState(false);

        return rtrim(implode(', ', $on), ', ') . rtrim(implode(', ', $off), ', ');
    }

    public function getInstancesByState($state)
    {
        return array_map(function($instance) use ($state) {
            if ($instance->getActive() === $state) {
                return $instance;
            }
        }, $this->collection);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$instance = new Instance('eu');
$instance->turnOn();

$instance2 = new Instance('us');
$instance2->turnOff();

$collection = new InstanceCollection();
$collection->add($instance);
$collection->add($instance2);

echo $collection;
```

And output:

> eu is switched on, us is switched off